# Save my cookie data to MySQL database?

Tags: php, javascript, database, cookies, offline

I was doing a survey I was offline server so I save users information in cookies,
I have users Information like this

**Fname:Ali,Lname:Kheiri,title:Director,org:Magiclamp,email:alikheiri@gmail.com
Fname:Ali,Lname:Kheiri,title:Director,org:Magiclamp,email:alikheiri@gmail.com**

it is save in cookies, but now i am online, so i want to save this cookies data in mysql database in php, javascript for this I write this code but its not working

```
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection05
    mysql_select_db("o2measure");
    if($_POST['submit']){
        $date = date('Y,m,d');
       $time = date("i:h:s",time() + $time_a);
       echo $session_id;
       $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        foreach($_COOKIE as $name => $cookie){
    // you can check any conditions based on cookie name $name
    $sql="INSERT INTO user_data (first_name, last_name, job_title, organisation, email, phone_number, ip_address, date, time)
     VALUES(" . mysql_escape_string($cookie) . ")";
        $result=mysql_query($sql); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get the cookie value as a string split it and have every criteria alone than use the insert query because the query you wrote is incorrect you saying insert into user_data the first name the last name the job title... but you are only giving him 1 value the $cookie but the sql don't know that the $cookie contain everything so you should first slpit the cookie value based on the ','