# It is possible to insert data in two different table in mysql by one insert query php?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save my cookie data to MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550441/save-my-cookie-data-to-mysql-database)

I am new in programming please co-operate with me. I have data in the form of this saved in cookies.
**1:3456,2:12346,3:345678,4:1,5:3,6:3333,7:234,8:456789,9:3,10:2,11:34567,12:456,13:,13:!!145!!,14:1,Fname:Muhammad,Lname:Riazz,title:Developer,org:Magiclamp,email:riaz_qadeer90@yahoo.com**

I want to save this data in one table **1:3456,2:12346,3:345678,4:1,5:3,6:3333,7:234,8:456789,9:3,10:2,11:34567,12:456,13:,13:!!145!!,14:1,**

and want to save this an other table **Fname:Muhammad,Lname:Riazz,title:Developer,org:Magiclamp,email:riaz_qadeer90@yahoo.com**

it is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to insert this with 1 query? Sole row INSERT queries aren't that exhausting for the database, so you might aswell just insert twice.

Basicly MySQL doesn't allow this.

[sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Comment: Does this answer the question?