# Get cookies in php?

Tags: php, cookies, get, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [It is possible to insert data in two different table in mysql by one insert query php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578599/it-is-possible-to-insert-data-in-two-different-table-in-mysql-by-one-insert-quer)

I have some users information saved in cookie, the users information are like this,

**Fname:Muhammad,Lname:Riaz,title:Developer,org:MagicLamp,email:riaz@yaho.com**

I want to insert these information in to mysql database , The problem is this how can I get these information from cookie and insert into database

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? What's your expected result vs actual result? Also, your code is littered with SQL vulnerabilities.

Comment: You should DEFINITELY use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Isn't this the 6th time you've asked this question now? And the second with this user account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're only creating one cookie, "user_token", which contains the serialized information you want. I think you want your foreach to iterate over the unserialized "user_token" cookie instead of all the cookies.