# Insert cookies data into MySQL database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cookies, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get offline cookies data with php and insert it in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578319/how-to-get-offline-cookies-data-with-php-and-insert-it-in-mysql)
>   [Get cookies in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579504/get-cookies-in-php)

I have some users information saved in cookie, the users information are like this,

**Fname:Muhammad,Lname:Riaz,title:Developer,org:MagicLamp,email:riaz@yaho.com
Fname:Fraz,Lname:Khan,title:Developer,org:MagicLamp,email:riaz@yaho.com**

I want to insert these information in to MySQL database. The problem is this: how can I get this information from a cookie and insert into database?

Comment: 2 user accounts. 7 copies of this question.

Comment: You allready asked this exact question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579504/get-cookies-in-php) and it got rated very low.  What makes you think reasking it will give you answers?

Comment: If the answer you got last time didn't solve the problem, why did you accept it as an answer?

Comment: Downvoted; you should never ask a question multiple times, as it (obviously) creates duplication of effort on your behalf.

Comment: Also replicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578599/it-is-possible-to-insert-data-in-two-different-table-in-mysql-by-one-insert-quer)!

Comment: Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578319/how-to-get-offline-cookies-data-with-php-and-insert-it-in-mysql), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552685/how-to-get-offline-cookies-data-with-php), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550441/save-my-cookie-data-to-mysql-database), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546717/how-to-save-data-in-mysql-from-cookies-in-php). I wasn't kidding when I said there were 7 copies of it.

Comment: I am new in programming, thanks for telling me my mistakes, and please appreciate me because i am new in programming

Comment: Good sleuthing Quentin. @user1393109 - please don't be offended if they all get closed. Questions don't get answered instantly on any forum, unless you are paying for the support. And why would you operate two separate accounts?

Comment: I operate separate account because the previous account have closed by stackoverflow. so I ask question by this account

Comment: @user1393109 - are you sure it has been closed? Normally your profile would be marked as suspended (it isn't) and you've not done anything to warrant an account closure (imo). Try again with it (get it to resend you a password), and please, stick to one account, and don't ask a question more than once. You should now have sufficient answered to help you - and don't be afraid to web-search around the answers to get you to the solution you need.

Comment: ([This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) is what a suspended account looks like).

Comment: Thanks Halfer to appreciate me......

Comment: I am using foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) but it is gets online cookies not offline

Comment: No, we will not appreciate your unwillingness to learn from your mistakes after they have been pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "";

foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value)
{
    $str .= $key . ":" . $value . ",";
}

$str = substr($str, 0, -1);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying and where i would write insert query...... after this code or before, can you help me a little more

Comment: I am using foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) but it is geting online cookies not offline

Comment: @user1393109: Sounds like you could use JavaScript cookies and then retry saving on the server via AJAX. Do some thorough web searching around these topics, and - *strongly recommended* - get a book on PHP web development to learn about the basics first. It will be worth the effort, I am certain.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out: [$_COOKIE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

After getting the cookie you can use [pdo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) to insert the data into the database.

Make sure you clean the data before inserting into the db.