# How to insert cookie data into mysql database php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I have an array of data saved in cookie, like this

```
1:good,2:accelent,3:bad,4:good,fname:Ahmad,lname:Riaz,title:Developer,org:Magiclamp,email:Riaz@khan.com
```

here i want to save this data in different tables
This in one table

```
1:good,2:accelent,3:bad,4:good
```

and this in another table

```
fname:Ahmad,lname:Riaz,title:Developer,org:Magiclamp,email:Riaz@khan.com
```

how can i solve this problem

Comment: Question is already asked 


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598201/insert-cookies-data-into-mysql-databas-inphp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the cookie using [$_COOKIE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php): `$cookie_val = $_COOKIE['NAME'];`

Split the input using [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php): `$cookie_array = explode(",", $cookie_val);`

From the result array use the values needed: `$cookie_array[0], $cookie_array[1] ...`

Clean the values before insertion into the db.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "1:good,2:accelent,3:bad,4:good,fname:Ahmad,lname:Riaz,title:Developer,org:Magiclamp,email:Riaz@khan.com";

$rows = explode(',', $str);

$data['table1'] = $data['table2'] = array();

foreach($rows as $k => $v) {
$a = explode(':', $v);
$data[(is_numeric($a[0]) ? 'table1' : 'table2')][$a[0]] = $a[1];
}

var_dump($data);
?>
```

That will split the data into two arrays.